# Rails server not running after updating to ruby 2.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

I was using rails 4.1.7 with ruby 2.0.0 and have developed an application.
Recently upgraded to ruby 2.1.4 and made that as "Local" setting using rbenv. Now after doing "gem install rails", everything installed well.

Question is now if I try to run server, i am getting error
***"Could not find rake-10.4.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."***

bundle show rake reveals that its installed under 
"bundle show rake
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.0"

Shouldn't this be under 2.1.4?

Comment: use rvm/rbenv to change ruby and gem space to another one, have you use one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) or [rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv) to change ruby and gem space to another one. If you will begin usage of the them do the following (**NOTE**: If you already use one of them, just begin with point 2):

1. [Install `rvm`](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) with ruby:

   ```
   $ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
   ```

   or [install `rbenv`](https://github.com/fesplugas/rbenv-insta), and then install ruby, and make it global:

   ```
   $ \curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fesplugas/rbenv-installer/master/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
   $ rbenv install 2.1.4
   $ rbenv global 2.1.4
   ```
2. Enter to the project, create two files `.ruby-version` with just installed version of `ruby` (in example `2.1.4`), and `.ruby-gemset` with name of your project:

   ```
   $ cd project-folder
   $ echo "2.1.4" > .ruby-version
   $ echo "your-project-name" .ruby-gemset
   ```
3. Fix `Gemfile` with newly intsalled version of `ruby` adding a line:

   ```
   ruby '2.1.4'
   ```
4. Reenter to the project folder, and `rvm` will generate its wrappers:

   ```
   $ cd .. ; cd project-folder
   ```
5. Issue gem installation:

   ```
   $ bundle install
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Will try and update here if it works fine.

Comment: I did a clean installation of ruby and set the dependeicies right. And all seems to be working fine now. I use ebenv for managing the version.
In point 2 above, .ruby-version already had 2.1.4. I did not create .ruby-gemset file. But things are working properly now.