# You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I got this error, for all gem that I try to install:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions into the **/var/lib/gems/1.9.1** directory.

obs. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According the question I see a few steps in order to allow writing to `/var/lib/gems`:

1. Create `gems` (if not any) group, and add yourself to the group:

   ```
   $ groupadd -f gems
   $ usermod -aG gems $(whoami)
   ```
2. When reenter to the session:

   ```
   $ sudo -u $(whoami) bash
   ```
3. Allow write for a `gems` group to `/var/lib/gems/`, and set the `setgid` bits:

   ```
   $ chown :gems /var/lib/gems/
   $ chmod g+sw /var/lib/gems/
   ```
4. Try installing gems into `/var/lib/gems/`.

**NOTE:** I strongly advice you to control rubies and gems via [rbenv](/questions/tagged/rbenv)/[rvm](/questions/tagged/rvm) keeping them in a local home folder. Please refer to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266154/446267) to know how to properly setup your project.

Comment: yeah, I tried to use RVM to install Ruby 2.1.5, and I got it. But when I try to install any gem, I get stucked. I use sudo, and could install the gems I want, run bundle install, but when I run rails s, I get an error about the gem.

Answer (score 1):

Either run with `sudo` or if that doesn't work, try `sudo chmod +w <file>` (from terminal separately)

Comment: well if you trust the file sure. python requires sudo to install stuff with pip so i don't see it as bad/unusual

Comment: How do I install gems into home folder?