# connect Rails application to a MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install MySQL adapter to connect my Rails application to a MySQL server, but when I try the command:

> gem install mysql2

it return this error message:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.

How can I fix it?

Thanks,RC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475311/you-dont-have-write-permissions-into-the-var-lib-gems-1-9-1-directory)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.9 directory.
means exactly that, you don't have permission to write there.

That is the version of Ruby installed by Apple, for their own use. While it's OK to make minor modifications to that if you know what you're doing, because you are not sure about the permissions problem, I'd say it's not a good idea to continue along that track.

Instead, I'll strongly suggest you look into using either rbenv or RVM to manage a separate Ruby, installed into a sandbox in your home directory, that you can modify/fold/spindle/change without worrying about messing up the system Ruby.

Between the two, I use rbenv, though I used RVM a lot in the past. rbenv takes a more "hands-off" approach to managing your Ruby installation. RVM has a lot of features and is very powerful, but, as a result is more intrusive. In either case, READ the installation documentation for them a couple times before starting to install whichever you pick.

Comment: Hi, I followed this guide: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html , and at first time when I create the hello world application, everything work. Later I have rebooted my computer, but when I tried to give command like "> rails .... etc" it return the error "the program rails could be found in these package: ruby-railtes-3.2, ruby-railtes-4.0"