# Error occured while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04

My ultimate goal is to get this to work in an Ubuntu 14.04 Docker container: https://github.com/byalextran/autoluv

When I run

```
m1@9bdc67007b49:~/autoluv$ bundle install --deployment
```

It says:

```
Fetching unf_ext 0.0.7.4
Installing unf_ext 0.0.7.4 with native extensions
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/m1/autoluv/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/.document
An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.7.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

But when I run

```
sudo gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

unf_ext-0.0.7.4 installs fine?

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...                                                                             
Successfully installed unf_ext-0.0.7.4                                                                                              
1 gem installed                                                                                                                     
Installing ri documentation for unf_ext-0.0.7.4...                                                                                  
Installing RDoc documentation for unf_ext-0.0.7.4...
```

I cannot figure out the next step. I've tried installing ruby-dev and gcc, but neither has helped move this along :(

Any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

I had this same problem and the reason was that I did not installed all the dependencies that bundler needs to run

just try to:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then run again

```
gem install bundler
```

and lastly

```
bundler
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are an Apple developer who is getting this error, this might be related to your Xcode command line tools selection.

Just run the following command with the path of the Xcode that you are using currently.

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Comment: this answer helped me .. I just want to know what does this do ? Does this switch terminal to use XCode's command line tools ?

Comment: Yes, you just specify which command line tools of the Xcode version you want to use/set as default.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between running commands with `sudo` and without. You can get more info about this command here `https://kb.iu.edu/d/amyi`.

`Errno::EACCES` usually happens when bunder has no access to a needed folder or it doesn't exist.

Try to `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.7.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` without `sudo`.

Comment: This keeps giving me file permission errors: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError): You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.

I am following the directions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475311/you-dont-have-write-permissions-into-the-var-lib-gems-1-9-1-directory), but it's like playing whack-a-mole. I've gotten to this error: "Operation not permitted - /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/unf_ext-0.0.7.4/ext/unf_ext/unf/trie/char_stream.hh," but even after chown and chmod, there's been no progress.

Comment: I followed the instructions here: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04 --- 

Should I use sudo rbenv install 2.5.3 and sudo rbenv global 2.5.3?

Comment: @Michael, no. You should run `rbenv install 2.5.3` and `rbenv global 2.5.3` without `sudo` if you want to use `bundle` command without `sudo` during development.

Comment: I'm confident that I followed that guide verbatim. I will better document my process and update the original question (comments don't allow for appropriate formatting). Thank you for everything thus far!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on Fedora.

I simply had to install the `gcc-c++` package.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error on Debian 10 buster in my ChromeOS Linux container by installing rbenv: `sudo aptitude install rbenv` or `sudo apt install rbenv`.

Aptitude package manager seems to be better at resolving dependencies and allowing me to install newer packages more easily than the default apt so I thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it after using following commands for Xcode 13, BigSur :

```
softwareupdate --install a

sudo   port upgrade outdated 

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

brew install wget

brew install build-essentials

bundler install
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the latest version of Ruby.
If you are using MacOS, system Ruby is old and outdated. you can not update the system Ruby, but you can install another version of Ruby and make it default global using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) ruby version manager tool.

finally you can install any ruby packages you like.